# Ruby's "gets" not working with japanese characters

Tags: ruby, unicode, cjk

I'm having trouble with getting japanese characters as user input through console.

I wrote a simple program to exemplify:

```
print "1> "
line1 = gets
print "2> "
line2 = gets
print "3> "
line3 = gets
puts line1 + line2 + line3
```

When I run it I get:

```
1> 古池や
2> 蛙飛び込む
3> 水の音
???
?????
???
```

I already checked it's not an output problem, as `print "おはよう"` works perfectly. So I'm assuming it's the input's fault. I'm running it on Win10 using PowerShell, so it may also be a console thing.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.4.3"
```

Also, when:

```
PS> Read-Host >> text.txt
お早う
```

text.txt is, efectively `お早う`

Ruby does seem to think it's UTF-8:

```
irb(main):001:0> Encoding.default_external
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

But since text.txt was created as `UTF-16 LE` (or `UCS-2 LE BOM`, depending on which text editor I ask) I'm guessing it's not.

I tried changing text.txt manually to UTF-8, and, when running the above, the file becomes: `��J0CQl�`

Comment: No problem on unix and zsh. Seems a windows problem.

Comment: What Ruby version are you using?

Comment: (1) Did you try redirecting input to a file (of the proper encoding)? This would verify, whether or not it is console-related. (2) Did you set your LANG environment variable properly? Maybe Ruby believes that the strings are of different encoding than they really are. If your environment is JIS and Ruby things it's UTF8, you are in trouble.

Comment: Editted the question in response to your comments. I now think I need to convert user input from UTF-16 to UTF-8 but still I couldn't find how.